# MySQL - Get Count value to 0 for Group By Date Value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I have a table like this-

```
CREATE TABLE sent_bulletin_list
(
    `id` int,
    `date` found_time,
    `value` int,
);
```

And I like to have a result of finding last 7 day total no of entries day by day.

What I have done is -

```
SELECT
DATE(found_time) as date,
count( * ) as total
FROM
sent_bulletin_list
WHERE
found_time > ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - ( 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 ) )
GROUP BY
DATE(found_time);
```

And finding something like this-

```
+------------+-------+
| date       | total |
+------------+-------+
| 2016-07-01 |     8 |
+------------+-------+
```

But I like to have something like this-

```
+------------+-------+
| date       | total |
+------------+-------+
| 2016-06-25 |     0 |
| 2016-06-26 |     0 |
| 2016-06-27 |     0 |
| 2016-06-28 |     0 |
| 2016-06-29 |     0 |
| 2016-06-30 |     0 |
| 2016-07-01 |     8 |
+------------+-------+
```

### Update-

I tried it with `case` like this-

```
count( CASE found_time IS NOT NULL 
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
      END AS date )
```

But it is also not working.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Are you using [tag:postgres] or [tag:mysql]? Those are two very different databases...

Comment: You want all data `sent_bulletin_list`?

Comment: MySQL @`Mureinik` .  @`Hebele` all group by data of those dates

Comment: @AbrarJahin Does it worked?

Comment: Do you want last 7 days result from now? Then the result set will include dates from `15-07-2016 ` to `21-07-2016`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a table where all the dates specified in the `date range` in your query reside.

You may give it a try:

```
SELECT 
dateTable.day,
COALESCE(your_query.total,0) AS total
FROM 
(
    SELECT DATE(ADDDATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - ( 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 )), INTERVAL @i:=@i+1 DAY)) AS DAY
    FROM (
    SELECT a.a
    FROM (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c
    ) a
    JOIN (SELECT @i := -1) r1
    WHERE 
    @i < DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()), FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - ( 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 )))
) dateTable

LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT
    DATE(found_time) as date,
    count( * ) as total
    FROM
    sent_bulletin_list
    WHERE
    found_time > ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - ( 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 ) )
    GROUP BY    DATE(found_time)
) your_query
ON dateTable.day = your_query.date
ORDER BY dateTable.day
```

---

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/afaa06/1/0)</kbd>

**Test:**

Suppose you have the following data in your table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sent_bulletin_list`;
CREATE TABLE `sent_bulletin_list` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `found_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO `sent_bulletin_list` VALUES ('1', '2016-07-17 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `sent_bulletin_list` VALUES ('2', '2016-07-17 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `sent_bulletin_list` VALUES ('3', '2016-07-17 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `sent_bulletin_list` VALUES ('4', '2016-07-17 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `sent_bulletin_list` VALUES ('5', '2016-07-17 00:00:00');
```

Then running the above query will give you the following output:

**Output:**

```
day         total
2016-07-14  0
2016-07-15  0
2016-07-16  0
2016-07-17  5
2016-07-18  0
2016-07-19  0
2016-07-20  0
2016-07-21  0
```

**Note:**

You need to put your `end and start date` range here:

`@i < DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()), FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - ( 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 )))`

And you need to put your `start date` here:

`SELECT DATE(ADDDATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - ( 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 )), INTERVAL @i:=@i+1 DAY)) AS DAY`

Comment: Have you tried with the sample data that I've provided?

Comment: Sorry to say, yes :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    DATE(A.found_time) as date,
    ISNULL(B.total, 0) AS total
FROM
    sent_bulletin_list A LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            DATE(found_time) as date,
            COUNT( * ) as total
        FROM
            sent_bulletin_list
        WHERE
            found_time > ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - ( 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 ) )
        GROUP BY
            DATE(found_time);
    ) B ON DATE(A.found_time) = B.date
```